# How to declare test scope dependencies in Leiningen?

Tags: testing, dependencies, leiningen

How to declare dependencies to be used in tests only, i.e. the deployed artefact doesn't need them?

The equivalent in [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) is `<scope>test</scope>`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The equivalent in [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html) is `% "test"`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.4.1.3" % "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the `:dev` profile:

```
(defproject your-project "1.0.0"
  :dependencies [[some-normal-library "1.0.0"]]
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[some-test-library "1.0.0"]]})
```

The Leiningen doc on [profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md#default-profiles) says:

> The :dev profile is used to specify project specific development
>   tooling. Put things here if they are required for builds or tests,
>   rather than just convenience tooling.